# Dashcode - Attributes Inspector - Design Guide?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, dashcode

In the Dashcode Inspector Window when you're on the Attributes tab with a Part selected there is a checkbox labeled "Design Guide".

I'm trying to find out what that is for. Anyone know?

It does not seem to be mentioned in the Dashcode User Guide. Are there any other docs for Dashcode 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well i have spent nearly an hour trying to see what effect if any it has and i cannot get anything anywhere to react whether it it is checked or not. I have Dashcode 3(333) installed.

Also i have trawled the literature, no i don't think there is any new documentation on version 3 and cannot find a mention anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for looking, but I had the same experience. No current docs. Hopefully Dashcode will receive more support sometime soon, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: I agree, i half suspect that it will suddenly have Pastrykit or Adlib wrapped up in it (which would be really cool)